# How to add menu to Acumatica button

Tags: erp, acumatica

I created graph in Acumatica. I also created button in the following way:

```
public PXAction<APBill> Report;
```

How can I convert this button into Menu button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose you the following way. Let's say your graph is named APBillManager, then in constructor you can write something like this:

```
public APBillManager()
{
    this.Report.AddMenuAction(bankStatementReport);
}

public PXAction<PRPayroll> bankStatementReport;
[PXButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Bank Statement")]
protected void BankStatementReport()
{
}
```